# Google Maps API V3 — Elements wont hide on click event toggle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been stuck on this for quite a while, so I would really appreciate some insight.

I'm trying to show the (two) Circles and an InfoWindow of a Marker on a click event, and then hide them when you click on it again. **The second click event doesn't work.** It shows me the stuff on click, but instead of hiding it on the second, it just loads the Circles and InfoWindow again.

Here's my code:

```
// Toggle Radii and InfoWindow — You can run, but you can't hide?
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    if ( ccArray[i].setMap() == null || iwcArray[i].setMap() == null ) {
        // First Click
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        ccArray[i].setMap(map);
        iwcArray[i].setMap(map);
    } else {
        // Second Click
        alert('You can hide, so just do it.');
        infowindow.open(null,marker);
        ccArray[i].setMap(null);
        iwcArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 'else if' should presumably just read 'else' - that may be causing gremlins?  You may have a problem with scope though, does the anonymous function have access to ccArray and iwcArray? If not, the null evaluation could always be true...

Comment: sorry, don't actually have the 'if' in my code, it was part of a fix i was trying earlier. i edited my code. i use both array variables throughout, so i suppose it must be a scoping issue. could you take a look? here's the full code — http://pastie.org/private/5pzziqjpcopfg9xfl0yag starting at _line 96_.

Comment: No, scope looks OK.  Your arrays should be accessible because they are defined within the same block.  In fact, because they aren't declared with 'var', they will be global. Let me look a bit more...

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Let me know how you get along. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Can you look at the value of 'i' when you click: console.log('i is ' + i);  ...and tell me if that is what you are expecting to see?

Comment: It logs the array position for that restaurant. It looks as though the else is never run because I can't get it to alert, or to log anything. **edit:** I did `console.log` inside of the click function.

Comment: clearOverlays() is resetting the value of i as it uses it as an iterator.  I'm not quite sure why you are initially setting i to the length of the array, but perhaps that makes sense to you.  You then add an item to the array, and later iterate using i, so i would be left as the original value plus 1.  In addition, there could be a scoping issue with the value of i that the anonymous function uses as it is effectively inside a closure, but look at the issue of using it in clearOverlays() first.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely look into it. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

"`if ( ccArray[i].setMap() == null || iwcArray[i].setMap() == null ) {`"

**ccArray** and **iwcArray** contain google.maps.Circle objects.

google.maps.Circle.setMap() is a function that returns nothing, setMap is used only to set the map property of the circle, not get it.  So I suspect that your code will always pass the test and never fall through to the else clause.

Are you sure you don't want to use ccArray[i].**getMap()** and iwcArray[i].getMap() ?

(see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle